# Split different entries into separate rows allowing only certain combinations

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have searched along the web for an answer, but, while similar questions have been asked, they were not the same and I have not been able use them.

I have a pandas dataframe in which several columns of text strings contains, sometimes, comma-separated values. I want to split each CSV field which contains these comma-separated values of three of them, creating a new row per entry, but in parallel, in this way (with A, C and D, not using E):

```
In [10]: before 
Out[10]: 
    A        B    C            D         E
0  a1,a2,a3  1    c1, c2, c3   d1,d2,d3  e1,e2,e3
1  a4        2    c4           d4        e4

In [11]: after
Out[11]: 
      A    B     C    D     E
0    a1    1    c1   d1    e1,e2,e3
1    a2    1    c2   d2    e1,e2,e3
2    a3    1    c3   d3    e1,e2,e3
3    a4    2    c4   d4    e4
```

The problem is, it should work for different tables, and all of these tables may have different columns (but always these three, A, C and D, in common, with the same names). And, plus, the other columns may have comma-separated values in some cells that have not be splitted, as it happened with E.

EDIT: These three columns will always have the same number of comma separated values in the same row, but it can vary between rows (1 value, 2 comma-separated values, 3 comma-separated values...).

I am sorry, I would like to offer some code, but I have not been able to make anything remotely useful.

Can someone help me? I would really appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that the three columns always have the same number of comma separated values you may do:

```
>>> df
          A  B         C         D         E
0  a1,a2,a3  1  c1,c2,c3  d1,d2,d3  e1,e2,e3
1        a4  2        c4        d4        e4
```

split each column:

```
>>> for col in ['A', 'C', 'D']:
...     df[col] = df[col].str.split(',')
... 
>>> df
              A  B             C             D         E
0  [a1, a2, a3]  1  [c1, c2, c3]  [d1, d2, d3]  e1,e2,e3
1          [a4]  2          [c4]          [d4]        e4
```

define the indexers:

```
>>> i = df['A'].map(len)
>>> j = np.repeat(np.arange(len(df)), i)
>>> k = np.concatenate(list(map(np.arange, i)))
```

expand the frame:

```
>>> df = df.iloc[j]
>>> df
              A  B             C             D         E
0  [a1, a2, a3]  1  [c1, c2, c3]  [d1, d2, d3]  e1,e2,e3
0  [a1, a2, a3]  1  [c1, c2, c3]  [d1, d2, d3]  e1,e2,e3
0  [a1, a2, a3]  1  [c1, c2, c3]  [d1, d2, d3]  e1,e2,e3
1          [a4]  2          [c4]          [d4]        e4
```

take one from each list:

```
>>> for col in ['A', 'C', 'D']:
...     df[col] = list(map(lambda xs, i: xs[i], df[col], k))
... 
>>> df
    A  B   C   D         E
0  a1  1  c1  d1  e1,e2,e3
0  a2  1  c2  d2  e1,e2,e3
0  a3  1  c3  d3  e1,e2,e3
1  a4  2  c4  d4        e4
```

Comment: Argh! I still cannot Vote up your answer, sorry :(

I have just realised that I did not say that they will always have the same number of comma separated values in the same row, but sometimes they will have only two comma separated values on each cell of the same row, other times they will be three values on each cell, and etc.

Will this affect the solution you provided? 

Thank you VERY MUCH in any case!

Comment: @Panda why don't you try/check it yourself if it will be affected by that?

Comment: Wow, this is beautiful. One issue (not sure if it's a general issue or not) is that I needed to change ```i``` to ```list(i)``` otherwise I got an error about casting the array from ```dtype('int64')``` to ```dtype('int32')```